# Harmonic functions locally null on connected open set

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let $u$ be a harmonic function on $U$ connected open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose there is a open set $V\subset U$, such that $u(x)=0$ for every $x\in V.$ Show that $u=0$ in $U$.

So, I tried to use of Maximum Principle but I not found a contradiction. Let be $x_0\in\partial V$ and $B=B(x_0,r)\subset U$. If I show that $u(x_0)$ is maximum or minimum is done. So, suppose there is $y\in B$ such that $u(y)\in\partial B$ is maximum in $B$.

How can I show this is not gonna happen? Some hint?

Thanks!

Comment: This follows from the "identity principle". See Theorem 5 in [these notes](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~boris/potential_th_notes.pdf)

Comment: @Luiz, thanks for your help, but I can't use properties of holomorphic functions in my course. Actually, I can to use just some tools of PDE.

Comment: Please look here http://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf Theorems 1.27 and 1.28